# Regular Expression match only one time in text editor?

Tags: javascript, regex

Using text editor [summernote](https://summernote.org/), I tried to match every character starting with `{{`, optionally `white space`, `any character`, optionally `white space`, and end with `}}`.

Therefore, I derived my regular expression pattern like this:

`var regex1 = /^\{\{\s*?\w+\s*?\}\}$/g;`

This would match: `{{matched}}` or `{{ matched }}`

```js
$('.wysiwyg').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onChange: function(contents, $editable) {
      // remove html tag
      contents = contents.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
      console.log('contens: ' + contents);

      var regex = /^\{\{\s*?\w+\s*?\}\}$/g;
      // update to local storage
      if (regex.test(contents)) {
        console.log('regex1 matched');
      }

    }


  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <form class="col-lg-12" id="postForm" action="/summernote.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Summernote test</legend>
        <p class="container">
          <textarea class="input-block-level wysiwyg" id="summernote" name="content" rows="18">
     </textarea>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it only matched if the starting of word is something like `{{matched}}`, and as contents is growing another subsequent matched after the first match like `{{another_matched}}` is not matched anymore. Simply say it matched only once time only if content start with matched pattern, eg. `{{matched}}`.

How can I make it to match a numbers of time the word, `{{matched}}` and `{{another_matched}}`, is matched ? Thanks.

Comment: If I understood what you're trying to say, then you just need to wrap your whole regex with `()+`

Comment: @GalAbra, Could you provide an example, pattern? Thanks.

Comment: [Here you go](https://regex101.com/r/2bo4AJ/1)

Comment: @GalAbra, Thanks. yet, as in text editor, the matched pattern does not always be next to one another all the time, they can be separated by some word, space, any punctuation mark, or new line, or it begin after some word. Ex, here start `{{first_matched}}` and `{{second_matched}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your regex only matches string that *completely* match the pattern i.e. whole string has to match.

This is because you added `^` and `$` at the start and end of the regex. These are anchors for the start and end of the string. It asserts that the string should start with your required pattern and also end with the required pattern, so something like this won't match:

```
Hello {{match}} Bye
```

Just remove the `^` and `$` and it will search the whole string for the pattern.

```
regex = /\{\{\s*?\w+\s*?\}\}/g;
regex.test('{{matched}} something {{matched}}') // true
```

Comment: Thanks very much you saved my day :)